# Remove file extension in listbox but retain it in tag

Tags: vb.net, winforms

The following code executes on load up and retrieves the file names from a directory

```
Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim lynxin As New IO.DirectoryInfo(sPath)
  lstPlanned.Items.Clear()
  For Each txtfi In lynxin.GetFiles("*.txt")
    lstPlanned.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txtfi.Name)) 'filename only
  Next
End Sub
```

What I would like is for it to pull back the information as above (without extension) but still have the ability to double click on the item in the listbox if need be to open the file. I know I can change the `lstPlanned.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txtfi.Name))` to `lstPlanned.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFile(txtfi.Name))` and the process will work however i do not want the file extension to show. I'm not sure if I should be looking at Parsing or replacing text.

Comment: You can put any object in a ListBox, not just a string.  So make a little class, override its ToString() method to return what you want to see.

Comment: You should probably respect the users preference in Explorer to show or hide extensions, unless the semantic meaning with your application has nothing to do with files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked Lisa-Berlin's answer for WinForms using ValueMember(), DisplayMember() and LINQ, but it has a couple errors in it.  Here's a cleaner example which also shows how to use the SelectedValue() member of the ListBox after a selection has been made:

```
Public Class Main

    Private spath = "C:\Users\Mike\Documents"

    Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Files = (From file In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(spath, "*.txt")
                     Select New With {
                         .FullName = file,
                         .FileNameWithoutExtension = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)}
                     ).ToList

        lstPlanned.ValueMember = "FullName"
        lstPlanned.DisplayMember = "FileNameWithoutExtension"
        lstPlanned.DataSource = Files
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstPlanned_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstPlanned.SelectedIndexChanged
        If lstPlanned.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            Label1.Text = lstPlanned.SelectedValue.ToString
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If lstPlanned.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            Process.Start(lstPlanned.SelectedValue.ToString)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim lynxin As New IO.DirectoryInfo(sPath)

lstPlanned.Items.Clear()

For Each txtfi In lynxin.GetFiles("*.txt")
    Dim i As New ListItem
    i.Value = txtfi.Name
    i.Text = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txtfi.Name)
    lstPlanned.Items.Add(i) 'filename only

Next
```

EDIT: If it is a Windows.Forms Project then try:

```
   Dim l = (From p1 In lynxin.GetFiles("d:\", "*.jpg")
             Select New With {.fi = New IO.FileInfo(p1),
                              .Name = .fi.Name.Replace(.fi.Extension, ""),
                              .Data = p1}
                          ).ToList

    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Data"
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
ComboBox1.DataSource = l
```

Comment: Thanks however I'm getting the that the ListItem in this line `Dim i As New ListItem` comes up as not being defined. I've tried all the suggestions it throws out to rectify but its not working properley. Thanks anyway....

Answer (score 1):

This is what Hans was referring to:

```
Class Element
   Public ItemName As String = ""
   Public ItemData As Object = Nothing

   Public Sub New(n As String, d as object)
       ItemName = n
       ItemData = d
   End Sub

   Public Sub New()
   End Sub

   Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
      Return ItemName
   End Sub
 End Class
```

To use it:

```
   For Each fi as in lynxin.GetFiles("*.txt")
         ' create an element, what you want to display is first arg
         ' second it the data to store
         Dim El AS New Element(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name),
               fi.Name)
         lstbox.add(El)
   Next
```

Syntax is as follows for accessing the data:

```
   console.WriteLine("file: {0}   fullname: {1}", _
        lstBox.Items(N).ItemName,  lstBox.Items(N).ItemData)
```

`lstBox.Items` no longer refers to a simple string, but an Element Object.  To get at the underlying data, qualify using the Element members: `lstBox.Items(N).ItemName` in this case returns the filename without Ext (`N` is a dummy variable), `.ItemData` in this case would be the full file name.

You can use a small class like that for lots of similar situations

Comment: Thanks - I'm getting "variable 'ToString' conflicts with function 'ToString' in the` base class 'Object' and should be declared shadows" within this part `Public Overrides ToString() As String
      Return ItemName
   End Sub` Also the N in this line  `lstPlanned.Items(N).ItemName, lstPlanned.Items(N).ItemData))` is coming up as not declared. Sorry not sure what the first statement means

Comment: sorry, that should be `Public Overrides Function ToString() As String` forgot the word function.  The last bit is just showing the syntax to get at the Elements and their parts once they are in a listbox: `lstBox.Items(N)` now equates to an Element object not a string, so you qualify what you want the ItemName or ItemData.